# What parts of a PE file are mapped into memory by the MS loader?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, loader, portable-executable

What parts of a PE file are mapped into memory by the MS loader?

From the PE documentation, I can deduce the typical format of a PE executable (see below).

I know, by inspection, that all contents of the PE file, up to and including the section headers, gets mapped into memory exactly as stored on disk.

**What happens next?**

Is the remainder of the file also mapped (here I refer to the Image Pages part in the picture below), so that the whole file is in memory exactly like stored on disk, or is the loader more selective than that?

In the documentation, I've found the following snippet:

> Another exception is that attribute certificate and debug information
>   must be placed at the very end of an image file, with the attribute
>   certificate table immediately preceding the debug section, because the
>   loader does not map these into memory. The rule about attribute
>   certificate and debug information does not apply to object files,
>   however.

This is really all I can find about loader behavior; it just says that these two parts must be placed last in the file, since they don't go into memory.

But, if the loader loads everything except these two parts, and I set the section RVA's suffiently high, then section data will actually be duplicated in memory (once in the mapped file and once for the position specified by the RVA)?

If possible, link to places where I can read further about loading specific to MS Windows.

[image]

Comment: Note the difference between loaded and mapped: even a giant exe doesn't actually have to be read from disk when it's mapped into memory.  You can map a big file and have it demand-paged into memory.  Your question title says "loaded" but you're asking about how the program-loader maps it.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: The entire PE file gets mapped into memory using the memory-mapped-file mechanism. Subsequent access attempts cause page faults, which trigger the loading. It seems that most of what you're asking about are implementation details on which you should not be relying. Intentionally undocumented, in other words. It is not clear what problem you're trying to solve. RVAs are simply offsets relative to the location where the file is memory-mapped, so I don't understand how there would be any duplication in memory.

Comment: @CodyGray - I'm not trying to solve a problem. This is just interest. However, if you know that the whole file gets mapped into memory, doesn't this imply that sections can be duplicated in memory (once for the file mapping and once for the specified RVA). Also, could you provide a source if possible :-) ?

Comment: @nlykkei: *"sections can be duplicated in memory (once for the file mapping and once for the specified RVA)"* - I do not understand, what you are trying to say here. But no, there is no duplication involved. *"could you provide a source if possible"* - As mentioned, these things are *"intentionally undocumented"*. No one writes documentation whose sole purpose is to document the undocumented nature of anything.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the file is always mapped into memory in one big chunk, but this isn't necessarily true. Instead each section can be mapped into memory separately. However this is only necessary if SectionAlignment > FileAlignment > 4096 (page size). Otherwise SectionAlignment == FileAlignment and because of the requirement that sections be contiguous and in VA order, both in memory and on disk, the section data can be mapped into memory in a single 1:1 mapping.

Comment: @RossRidge, you're confusing mapping (linking to virtual memory) with loading (transfer from disk to RAM). Mapping happens in one fell swoop. Loading happens in 4k blocks.

Comment: Doesn't VirtualSize>RawSizeOfData troubles that?

Comment: @Johan  No, if SectionAlignment > FileAlignment >= 4096 then its not possible to map the executable in "one fell swoop".  If SectionAligment is 8096 and FileAlignment is 4096 and every section's VirtualSize is 1 then VirtualAddress values of the sections will be 2000h, 4000h, 6000h, but the PointerToRawData values will be 1000h, 2000h, 3000h,.

Answer (score 1):

Finding this information is like an egg hunt, because MS always insists on using its own terminology when the COFF description uses AT&T terms.

> What parts of a PE file are mapped into memory by the MS loader?

It depends.
All sections covered by a section header are mapped into the run-time address space.
However sections that have an [RVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF#Relative_virtual_address) of 0 are not mapped and thus never loaded.

> Each debug directory entry identifies the location and size of a block of debug information. The RVA specified may be 0 if the debug information is not covered by a section header (i.e., it resides in the image file and is not mapped into the run-time address space). If it is mapped, the RVA is its address.

Memory contains an exact replica of the file on disk.
Note that executables and dll's are mapped into virtual memory, not physical!
As you access the executable parts of it are swapped into RAM as needed.

If a section is not accessed then it obviously does not get swapped into physical RAM, it is however still mapped into virtual memory.

You can read up on everything you might ever want to know [about PE files (and more) on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).

Your quote is lifted from the [documentation of the `COFF` file format](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/03wi/lectures/LinkerFiles/coff.pdf).
The critical part is:

> The rule on attribute certificate and debug information does not apply to object files.

From: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121460

> Size: Size of the optional header, which is included for executable files but not object files. An object file should have a value of 0 here.

Ergo: executable files or not object files, they are image files.
as such the exception to the rule does not apply to them.

Comment: *"When swapping pages into RAM the OS also fixes up relocations."* - That's not correct. All relocations are done at load time, if a module cannot load at its preferred load address. Memory pages that were changed during this process no longer match the contents of the module on disk, and need to be paged out (vs. being discarded) in case the OS needs more physical memory. No relocations are performed when memory gets paged in (it's either done already at load time, or not necessary).

Comment: @IInspectable, in Win10 the relocations are done in a JIT manner as described, because ASLR makes relocations mandatory.

Comment: ASLR doesn't change anything. It is applied at load time, so the relocations are still fixed up when an image is mapped. Addresses don't change dynamically while a process is running!

Comment: @CodyGray, you're twisting what I said. The latest Win10 build fixes up relocations JIT. Before execution, but **after** mapping. That means if a 4k block is never executed then it will never have its relocations touched.  This is different from pre Win10/early Win10. Obviously the relocs happen before execution time.

Comment: @CodyGray, it's introduced in Redstone aka anniversary update of Win10. See: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=323 anyway, removed the section because its off-topic really.

Comment: @Johan - The PE documentation explicitly differs between two types of files: image (executable) files and object files. This is stated in the first pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and link. I haven't updated to the latest build of Win10 yet, and although Alex's blog is on my list of blogs to read, I am behind. :-)

Comment: @nlykkei, read what it says here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx  PE files are COFF OBJ files.

Comment: There are two kinds of PECOFF files, both using the same basic data structures but with different constraints, object files and image files. Object files are input to the linker, image files (executables and DLLs) are the output of the linker. The PECOFF spec makes this clear when it defines what an object file is: "A file that is given as input to the linker. The linker produces an image file, which in turn is used as input by the loader." In the case of a image file like an executable, the debug and certificate information must be at the end of the file and isn't mapped into memory.

Comment: @Johan: as the article you linked to explains, the JIT fixups are only for dynamic relocations used by kernel-mode images. For user-mode PE images, relocations are still done by the loader, which runs in user mode in the address space of the process that loads the EXE/DLL image. At that time, the process base has already been determined, and obviously the loader needs to touch the pages containing memory references that are being relocated. This also means that your statement "Memory contains an exact replica of the file on disk" is not correct.